# why typedef struct in a header file in C?

Tags: c, struct, header, typedef

I saw some code in C header like this:

```
//a.h

typedef struct name name;

//a.c

struct name {
   int number;
   int age;
};
```

what is the reason why `typedef struct` in header file?  and kind of implement it in source file?

Why not just define the struct in header file? what is the propose of doing this?

Comment: did you mean `struct name` instead of `struct a`?

Comment: Voting to reopen, since I think the real question is "why not just define the struct in header file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typedef` keyword is used to create synonyms, so that later in your code you can use just your `typedef`ed keyword instead of `struct` or any primitive type you replaced.

Comment: While you're very right, I don't think this is the anser OP is looking for. What you told is already known to him/her. Google about _opaque type_ :-)